# Structuring Data for Pandas / Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, data-structures

I have a raspberry pi collecting air quality data which I am looking to push to a webserver using flask. My problem lies in the way I originally structured the text file to store the data - which is as follows:

```
> (Sun Aug  9 08:59:05 2020,  PM1.0 ug/m3 (ultrafine particles):        
> 20 PM2.5 ug/m3 (combustion particles, organic compounds, metals): 30
> PM10 ug/m3  (dust, pollen, mould spores):                      32
> PM1.0 ug/m3 (atmos env):                                       19
> PM2.5 ug/m3 (atmos env):                                       29 PM10
> ug/m3 (atmos env):                                        32
> >0.3um in 0.1L air:                                            3990
> >0.5um in 0.1L air:                                            1089
> >1.0um in 0.1L air:                                            180
> >2.5um in 0.1L air:                                            10
> >5.0um in 0.1L air:                                            2
> >10um in 0.1L air:                                             0 ), (Sun Aug  9 09:00:06 2020,  PM1.0 ug/m3 (ultrafine particles):        
> 21 PM2.5 ug/m3 (combustion particles, organic compounds, metals): 31
> PM10 ug/m3  (dust, pollen, mould spores):                      33
> PM1.0 ug/m3 (atmos env):                                       20
> PM2.5 ug/m3 (atmos env):                                       30 PM10
> ug/m3 (atmos env):                                        33
> >0.3um in 0.1L air:                                            3990
> >0.5um in 0.1L air:                                            1089
> >1.0um in 0.1L air:                                            180
> >2.5um in 0.1L air:                                            10
> >5.0um in 0.1L air:                                            2
> >10um in 0.1L air:                                             0 ), (Sun Aug  9 09:01:06 2020,  PM1.0 ug/m3 (ultrafine particles):        
> 21 PM2.5 ug/m3 (combustion particles, organic compounds, metals): 31
> PM10 ug/m3  (dust, pollen, mould spores):                      33
> PM1.0 ug/m3 (atmos env):                                       20
> PM2.5 ug/m3 (atmos env):                                       30 PM10
> ug/m3 (atmos env):                                        33
> >0.3um in 0.1L air:                                            3990
> >0.5um in 0.1L air:                                            1089
> >1.0um in 0.1L air:                                            180
> >2.5um in 0.1L air:                                            10
> >5.0um in 0.1L air:                                            2
> >10um in 0.1L air:                                             0 ),
```

As you can see, the data is probably not structured well for my intention and below shows what I have done using Pandas with the hope to provide a data visualisation using matplotlib.

```
sample_data = pd.read_fwf('particulates.txt',  header=None)
```

This returns a dataframe which looks as follows:
[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBNLc.png)

I have been trying to figure out the best way of arranging the data so that:

- The date, which shows on the first column of each new record and is
  seperated by a ' , '  can be used as my x axis.
- Each other data point - such as'PM1.0 ug/m3 (ultrafine particles):' can be grouped together for a relevant data plot.

I am more looking for pointers on the best way to achieve this rather then the solution itself. One way that I was considering was to use heavy string manipulation and use of modulo, since the data has exactly 14 lines per record, to move this to a SQL database, however, no doubt this can be achieved using Pandas.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated and thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sample_data = pd.read_csv('particulates.txt',  sep=':')
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I should have noted that I was trying to do this before and had used variations of this and ended up achieving the same results as what your solution provides  with this - sample_data[[0,3]]). With this dataframe, my problem still remains that I am trying to get to a point where I use the date as the x dimension and the rest of the headings as y dimension. That is my gap in knowledge of pandas and matplotlib. How would I go about specifying the date as the x dimension and the rest as the y dimension? Would this be using a dictionary of sorts?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I can't comment yet, but your question was answered by gtomer, so give him the credits. Your data will be already structured for use in matplotlib.

If you want to use the date as x dimension, use the following code:

```
sample_data.set_index(['date'])
```

After that, just use:

```
sample_data.plot(subplots = True)
plt.show()
```